# Resize DT::datatable() column size on the fly using mouse in a shiny app with javascript or other way

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

Is it possible to resize all columns of a `DT::datatable()` on the fly with the mouse like in excel using some javascript?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```